# How to change JPA default fetching to LAZY

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to change by default loading of all beans to lazy
we can change it manually by changing every join fetch type to lazy but is there any way that I can change the default value of JPA so I don't have to change it manually

I am using spring boot project is there any way I can change it from `application.properties` file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if there was a global configuration like this (and there is none) your `JOIN FETCH` on the query level would override that setting anyway. The way the queries are structured always takes higher precedence than that of the global set-up.

Regarding the situation where you only use `JOIN` without the `FETCH`, the persistence provider may still decide to use `EAGER` fetching anyway:

> The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime that
>   data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed. The
>   implementation is permitted to eagerly fetch data for which the LAZY
>   strategy hint has been specified.

So there is no way to 100% ensure LAZY loading throughout the project.