# How can I set the default fetch type for Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a crufty old Java Enterprise program that I'm trying to bring into the current decade thanks to security audits flagging half the code it imports as being a security risk. As some of you know, somewhere in the mid 2010's Hibernate changed its defaults from LAZY loading for everything, to EAGER loading for almost everything.

Problem is, this breaks this program bad. It was annotated assuming everything was lazy loading, so the only annotations are for things that it wanted to fetch EAGER, which, uhm, wasn't much. The end result is a huge increase in the number of joins, which has caused performance to plummet disastrously because most of the joined entities aren't used in a typical batch operation. For example, the User field is necessary in order to query by user. But the user for a report is already fetched at the top of the loop that processes the user's records, so adding a JOIN to the query to eager fetch the user for each and every record just makes the report slower.

Most of my relationships aren't annotated for lazy fetching, and there's a *lot* of them. I could manually go in and, laboriously, one by one, annotate them for lazy fetching. Or I could change Hibernate's defaults back to what they were back when this program was written. I'd obviously much prefer the latter, for obvious reasons -- I really don't want to be spending any more time updating this antique code base than I have to, since we're in the process of writing its replacement.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57586036/19351325 unfortunately there's no way to change the default fetch type, it will always be:

```
OneToMany: LAZY
ManyToOne: EAGER
ManyToMany: LAZY
OneToOne: EAGER
```

**But** you can use simple regex to automatically add Lazy fetching. In Intellij Idea use these combinations: ctrl+shft+r or cmd+shft+r, and the following regex: @ManyToOne$ or @OneToOne$ , for replace-section use: @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) and @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) accordingly.

If you already have in these annotations some properties added you can just modify your search regex. Anyway it will be faster then doing it all manually

Comment: I unfortunately had to go through and manually annotate each and every domain class to manually set LAZY or EAGER as needed. Just another instance of the Hibernate developers not caring about application developers -- changing defaults in mid-stream and then forcing developers to do unnecessary work in order to justify the Hibernate developers' salaries. I know they have to make a living, but why couldn't they make the defaults settable instead of forcing arbitrary defaults on everybody?

Answer (score 0):

There is a default fetch plan based on the mapping you provide while defining entities.

- By default, the JPA @ManyToOne and @OneToOne annotations are fetched EAGERly, while the @OneToMany and @ManyToMany relationships are considered LAZY.
- This is the default strategy, and Hibernate doesn’t magically optimize your object retrieval, it only does what is instructed to do

Comment: Based on your use case, you can try to optimise or override the default behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, as is obvious in my question. My question asks how to change that default fetch plan. Unfortunately it appears impossible -- so I did have to laboriously go into each and every domain file and manually annotate it to LAZY except for the few things I wanted to remain EAGER.